# Ionic - correct way to store and display same info in different screens

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a newbie in mobile development.

So, my Ionic 4 app is working good, but I'm a bit confused on storing and displaying data.

Basically, when open the app I'm requesting all app and user information from an API.

It's working and I'm storing in NativeStorage.

So, how to use this data after stored? Consider that same information will be displayed in many places, like the user name.

Should I read NativeStorage on every page `ionViewWillEnter`?

Or maybe should I read storage from a `user.service` and keep the information inside this service?

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shailesh has a correct answer.
Another method (for larger projects - where data management is more complex) is to use  Redux pattern.

If you are using ionic with angular then search for ngrx, if using ionic wityh react use Redux.

I think it is better to try using services with observables from (RxJs) as @ShaileshBhokare mentioned as a newbie, or if your project don't require complex data management, because Redux pattern is complex to be understood.

To use with services, look at my example (sample-data-service.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleDataServiceService {

  sampleData1: string[]; // in a component, you wil not know if this data changed

  sampleData2Behaviour =  new BehaviorSubject([]);
  sampleData2: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.initializeDataFromDatabase();
  }

  initializeDataFromDatabase() {
    this.sampleData1 = ['a', 'b'];
    this.sampleData2 = ['x', 'y'];
    this.sampleData2Behaviour.next(this.sampleData2);
    // need to subscribe to thisSubjectBehaiour if you want to get changes (INPORTANT: Don't forget to unsubscribe) 
    // at the start of any component where you want to use this data, you could use sampleData2Behaviour.getValue();
  }

  changeSampleData1(someParam: string) {
    //do what you need
  }
  changeSampleData2(someParam: string) {
    //do what you need to change sampleData2
    this.sampleData2Behaviour.next(this.sampleData2)
  }


}
```

In the component:

```
    constructor (private sampleDataService: SampleDataService){}

        ngOnInit() {
            // subscribe to get notified when data changes
            this.sampleDataService.sampleData2Behaviour.subscribe(
              sampleDataFromService => this.inComponentSampleData = [...sampleDataFromService] // because it is an array in this case
            );

            // to get the data initially, because data initially will be retrieved in the service before you subscribe to the behaviour
            this.inComponentSampleData = this.sampleDataService.sampleData2Behaviour.getValue();
          }
ngOnDestroy(){
this.sampleData2Behaviour.unSubscribe();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! could you please add an example of component subscribing/unsibscribing it?

Comment: Found a good article about `BehaviourSubject` https://www.joshmorony.com/using-behaviorsubject-to-handle-asynchronous-loading-in-ionic/

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your request. the link you mentioned is useful

Answer (score 1):

You can read user information in the app.component and store that data in services. Whenever you need user information you can simply retrieve it from services.

Calling storage every time is not a good idea.

Happy coding :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer! just to make things clear, could you explain why isn't a good idea calling storage everytime?